# At the end of a reporting period, how do I record increased/decreased share values?

Tags: shares, double-entry

How do I record changes in the values of shares that I hold at the close of a reporting period in double-entry accounting? I.e., what transactions are made?

I am interested in any standard or typical ways of recording such changes for shares that I hold personally, as investments for the future.

Comment: Accounting questions are off-topic, and the GAAP rules for recording equity investments are complicated for a business, but if you rephrase your question from more of a personal finance (i.e. in an app like Quicken or GnuCash) you might get a helpful answer.

Comment: @DStanley I thought I made it clear that it was for personal finance., I don't see that the answer should be software-specific, but in case it's helpful, I'm using Gnucash.

Answer (score 1):

For personal accounting (i.e. your own "balance sheet") you *could* create an entry for "unrealized gain" that you would then need to clear out when you sell the stock and it becomes "realized". You'd also have to decide *when* to account for unrealized gains - once a year? Once a month? Or just leave the value at cost and track unrealized investment gains elsewhere (since it doesn't really matter until you realize the gains)

Businesses typically do not record unrealized gains in the balance sheet except in certain circumstances, the details of which are off-topic for this forum. (search for "Cost Method and "equity Method" for details)

Comment: I did say that I want to do it "at the end of the reporting period", which implies that it could be whenever I choose. In another related thread, it was stated that this is usually done at the end of the reporting period, which is why I used the term. I might pick monthly or I might pick quarterly or I might pick annual. It's really for the purpose of tracking net worth.